FUYU Persimmon - how much better is a grafted tree?
I've been wanting to plant a persimmon tree for a while, but there has been a shortage of them for sale due, as I understand it, to a lack of people to do grafting (I live in NZ - so an island with plant import restrictions)
I possibly have the opportunity to purchase a 3 year old FUYU grown from a cutting from a home gardener in a pot (so true to type fruit) which is showing its first flowers - or, for a comparable price - but a lot more hassle as its quite far away - get a much smaller grafted major nursery plant which will fruit in 2-3 years.
I've been unable to discover what rootstock the nursery uses.   Also - if it makes a difference - I need to contend with an environment with clay soil. (I plan to amend the soil and mound the plant to try mitigate this)
Can anyone advise if FUYU persimmons particularly benefit from grafting or if this is mainly a convenient way for a nursery to grow true-to-type plants faster?

I don't know about the rootstock benefit, or lack thereof, in persimmon specifically, but I do know that the generally accepted advice for planting a tree in "bad soil" is to just plant it without trying to modify what amounts to a pot's worth of soil where it goes. Idea being you want the roots to grow out of the initial planting hole to make a strong tree. If they find the planting hole soil much improved, they can act as if they are in a pot and get rootbound. If you elevate/mound it, that's fine, just pay attention to the soil level as grown and keep it the same when planted.

If it matters (but then you'd expect the nursery to say) it seems that dwarfing is a common reason to graft. But in general grafting is simply more efficient for the nursery, so non-dwarfs are grafted onto "standard" rootstocks. In other fruits it's not uncommon for particular rootstocks to provide resistance to certain diseases, etc, but I'm not seeing anything in the little research I've done mentioning that for persimmons.

Lacking input from anyone more "in-the-know" about persimmons specifically, the only specific "benefit" I found with regard to persimmon grafting was dwarfism, and if it's not mentioned by the nursery, it's probably not dwarfing rootstock.
I did find several mentions of grafting Fuyu to generic persimmon rootstock as a normal thing, and to people growing it from cuttings.
One advantage to growing it from cuttings, particularly if the supply is tight where you are, is that you can make root divisions for propagation as well as rooting twigs. It will also mean that if for some reason the top of the tree is severely damaged by wind or storm, whatever grows back from the roots will still be Fuyu.
